# How MySQL selects indexes?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table named `my_table` with columns `did`, `uid` and `pid`.
The indexes for this table are:

- `(uid, did, pid)` - unique
- `(did)`
- `(did, pid)`

Now I have the a query that looks like this:

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE did=1234

This query matches ~150k rows in ~12 sec; but if I remove the last index it finishes in ~1sec

Can somebody explain what is happening?

Comment: Sounds like an edge case. Pls do an analyze table. If result is still slow post full table structure and result of explain and also indicate total number of rows in table

Comment: **Pro tip**: Avoid `SELECT *` . Instead give a list of the columns you need. Sometimes the query planner can take advantage of that list to optimize your query.

Answer (score 0):

The first query probably found that most of the blocks it needed were sitting on disk.  Hence the 12 seconds was mostly I/O.  Then the second query found everything it needed was cached in the buffer_pool, so it could run 10 times as fast.

For further discussion, please do:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ... -- for both cases
SHOW CREATE TABLE -- there are _many_ things here that _may_ impact your question
How much RAM do you have?
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
```

Since `INDEX(did, pid)` can do whatever `INDEX(did)` wants to do, it is *usually* good to drop the *shorter* index.